# How to install Linux Porteus on an Acer Aspire SW5-012?

Tags: linux, grub2, acer-aspire

I would like to install Linux Porteus on my Acer Aspire SW5-012 tablet. It has an atom processor which is 64-bit but a UEFI bootloader which is 32-bit.

I was told that I could use Grub2 and make 64-bit Linux Porteus compatible. It only has the 32-bit Windows 10. I haven't been able to get it to boot to either the 32-bit Linux Porteus or the 64-bit Linux Porteus.

I used RUFUS to create a bootable USB for both versions. I used Grub2 to alter the EFI but it doesn't seem to stick. I need to find a cfg file to load into Grub2.

I'm completely lost. I have had no luck.

Comment: I cleaned up the question, but [your original title was “Acer Aspire SW5-012”](https://superuser.com/posts/1820464/revisions) which is not a question. Please be sure to actually _ask_ a question in the title; just posting a machine name and model number is not a question.

Answer (score 0):

As your problem is that you could not boot linux on an acer, have a look at the answer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1822742/how-to-install-any-linux-on-acer-aspire-a515-48m-with-amd-ryzen-5-cpu/) which worked for me, to resolve booting linux on an acer that refused to boot linux, however, it is for a different acer model, and different acer models seem to have different problems installing and/or booting linux. At least it should give you some ideas in the right direction.